# how to convert timestamp string to date in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, timestamp

how to convert timestamp string to date in c# 
for example i need convert 40504 to 2010/11/22 like excel

Comment: What kind of timestamp? How is it obtained? How is it calculated?

Comment: 40504 appears to be an excel/OA date ... and a check with Excel confirms it.

Comment: @Tim Barrass - it's possible, and I agree that the word `excel` in the question suggests this, however, I'd rather be _sure_ before giving a possibly incorrect answer.

Comment: @Oded +1 (in all seriousness) for being a conscientious community member (but your timescales and flow are too quick for me -- is rounding out your answer over a period of minutes frowned on?).

Comment: @Tim Barrass - Not at all, don't mind _rounding off_ of a _correct_ answer. If you start _completely_ incorrectly, I will downvote. I removed the downvote once you have a _semi_ correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit: sorry, DateTime.FromOADate(double date) iirc -- link to msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx) ...

and to clarify I'm proposing this if your 40504 int is an excel (OA) date that you want to convert ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx) constructor of the DateTime structure. It receives only one parameter as an `Int64` that represents the ticks. But a timestamp in ticks is represented by a longer number than the one you exemplified. Consider giving more details on the data/time representation.